# Search a word from loacdatabase and trying to get #category and #word IOS/ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]
I have a table of words and I'm trying to search a word "Fine" and trying to console #category and #word my Query is

```
NSString *query = [NSString
stringWithFormat:@"Select field1, field2, field3 FROM words WHERE field3 = '%@ '", @"Fine"];
FMResultSet *result =[db executeQuery:query];
while([result next])
 {
     NSLog(@"words  %@ %@ " ,
    [result stringForColumn:@"field1"],
    [result stringForColumn:@"field2"]);

 }
```

when i run the query nothing is show and complier not going into while Body , if any one get the error then post a comment...

Comment: remove the space `@"Select field1, field2, field3 FROM words WHERE field3 = '%@'"` and try once, check this `'%@'` isnot `'%@ '`

Comment: but Not working this query ...

Comment: what is the output you get from `result`

Comment: this query nothing shows and compiler not going into while body it means result is nil or not contain any data ,